# RoR - Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, activeadmin

I am working on Ruby on Rails application. I am trying to upgrade the rails version from 4.2 to 5.0

I have changed the rails dependency in engine's gemspec file.

On running `bundle update` in engine it is showing the following error -

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.2.4.4, which depends on
        actionmailer (= 5.2.4.4)

    simple_token_authentication was resolved to 1.17.0, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 3.2.6, < 7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.2.4.4, which depends on
        actionpack (= 5.2.4.4)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.2)

    simple_token_authentication was resolved to 1.17.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.2.6, < 7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    paranoia (~> 2.2) was resolved to 2.4.3, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0, < 6.2)

    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.2.4.4, which depends on
        activerecord (= 5.2.4.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    factory_girl_rails was resolved to 4.9.0, which depends on
      factory_girl (~> 4.9.0) was resolved to 4.9.0, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.2.4.4, which depends on
        activesupport (= 5.2.4.4)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      activeadmin (= 1.0.0.pre2) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre2, which depends on
        rails (>= 3.2, < 5.0)

    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    factory_girl_rails was resolved to 4.9.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0.0)

    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.2.4.4, which depends on
        railties (= 5.2.4.4)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2)
```

I tried to delete gemfile.lock of engine and run command `bundle install` then it is showing the following error -

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      activeadmin (= 1.0.0.pre2) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre2, which depends on
        rails (>= 3.2, < 5.0)

    engine1 was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      engine2 was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
        rails (~> 5.0)
```

Do anyone have any idea how to resolve it? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Re-read the error message, it says exactly what's going on.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
```

There is no single version of rails that satisfies all requirements. From your issue description I see that you're trying to update to 5, so lets see what is not okay with 5.

```
In Gemfile:
  engine was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
    activeadmin (= 1.0.0.pre2)
```

Engine depends on activeadmin with a fixed version

```
was resolved to 1.0.0.pre2, which depends on
  rails (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
```

This version requires rails of at least 3.2 and less than 5.0. This disallows rails 5. You'll need to update activeadmin in engine before you update rails in the application using the engine.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have updated the active admin version and now it is showing me another error saying - ```simple_token_authentication was resolved to 1.15.1, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 3.2.6, < 6)```

Comment: This looks fine, rails 5 depends on actionmailer 5 which is between 3.2.6 and 6, so it's fine. The issue is somewhere else unless you accidentally upgraded to rails 6. Follow the papertrail and see which gem is unhappy with rails 5.